# Hive .g.dart file not getting generated

Tags: flutter, local-storage, flutter-hive

I want to use Hive for local database for storage.
This is my model class

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'addForm.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class AddForm extends HiveObject{

  @HiveField(0)
  String title;

  @HiveField(1)
  String description;

  @HiveField(2)
  int fieldNumber;

  @HiveField(3)
  String question;

  @HiveField(4)
  Widget fieldType;

  @HiveField(5)
  bool required;

}
```

I use use this command: "flutter packages pub run build_runner build" to generate .g.dart file but it's not generating.

I tried everything but nothing is working please help!

Comment: In your case probably a error is thrown because `Widget` is no `HiveType`. In your terminal you should see the reason.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for who made the same mistake.

Because I faced the same problem. In my case, my `part '..';` was the same name as class name just like your code above. This won't work, you should name the part as the name of your `file_name.dart` not in your class `ClassName`.

for example.

if your file name is `add_form.dart` then your part is `part 'add_form.g.dart';`

also, hive doesn't support widget.

Answer (score 1):

It may be late, but my answer may help those who are faced with the same problem.

In my case, my `pubspec.yaml` did not contain `hive_generator`

After installing it, I solved this problem. To install `hive_generator`:

```
flutter pub add hive_generator
```

Answer (score 0):

`HiveField`s may only have types that are directly supported by `Hive` or are `HiveType`s. `Widget` is neither, which is why you cannot save a widget unless you have written a corresponding adapter yourself.

Your terminal should also show this as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , without (typeId:0)..
@HiveType()
class MyNote extends HiveObject {}

Comment: please use code format

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to first clean the build cache and get the dependencies.

To clean the cache:

```
flutter clean
```

To install the build cache:

```
flutter pub get
```

Then run the command:

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Answer (score 0):

I
have also faced this issue . i solved it by adding [hive_generator](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_generator) Package and run build runner again.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue, i re-run the same command and the file generated :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).